# References on Pricing commodity forwards

Tags: derivatives, forward, commodities

Any good reference on pricing simple forward contracts with source code? Thanks

Comment: How does this differ from you own question http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30859/how-to-price-a-commodity-forward where you provide a formula and reference German's book?

Comment: @noob2: Thanks - copy/paste error.

Comment: Also it might help if you gave a hint what commodity (or commodities) you are concerned with. Energy, metals, ... . What issues require going beyond the simple formula that you gave previously.

Comment: @noob2 Thanks mate. I'm looking to price any LME forward. I would appreciate any hints or recommendations. Thanks